# The requested URL was not found on this server in CodeIgniter 4

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter, url, codeigniter-4

I added url helper in Base Controller

```
protected $helpers = ['url'];
```

also call it in Home Controller

```
class Home extends BaseController
{
    public function index()
    {
        helper("url");
        return view('index');
    }

    public function data()
    {
        helper("url");
        return view('welcome_message');
    }
}
```

`.htaccess` file in public folder

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond $1 !^(index.php|resources|robots.txt)

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
```

also remove index.php from app.php file

```
public $indexPage = '';
```

Comment: What URL are you requesting? Does it work if you request the root (no URL-path)?

Comment: Your use of the URL helper seems redundant. In addition, the [URL helper is automatically loaded by the framework on every request](https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/helpers/url_helper.html#loading-this-helper).

Comment: public $baseURL = 'http://localhost/codeigniter/public/';   this is the URL I am using the first page is working properly but when I click on another page it shows  error @MrWhite

Comment: I follow this link but its not working @steven7mwesigwa

Comment: You should instead make your apache or nginx `DocumentRoot` configuration point to the public folder of your project. Then declare `app.baseURL = 'http://localhost'` in the `.env` file of your root project directory.

Comment: Is there a specific reason why you chose to remove `index.php` declaration from the `app.php` file?